# Advanced digitizing and measurement tool

Tags: qgis, digitizing, measurements

I want to draw a polygon with 18m x 2m using the advanced digitizing tool. When I measure the size after creating with the measurement tool, the lengths of the sides do not match up (drawn sides vs measurements with measurement tool).

[image]

According to the advanced digitizing tool, the polygon in the picture is 18m long.

I am using QGIS 3.14 and a WGS 84 pseudomercator projection (EPSG 3857).

Comment: Distance measurements in Web Mercator are always wrong (unless both points are on the Equator), so it doesn't seem like you have a chance here.

Comment: I have a georeferenced surveyor map in this project and the results of the measurement tool add up with the measurements of the surveyor. So this means that the advanced digitizing tool is wrong here? Which projection would you recommend for this task?

Comment: My suggestion would be to set your map to a UTM zone appropriate for your area instead of Web Mercator (just for google maps and distorted in shape and area). The distances will be correct when you create the polygons.